# How to call a setState with data from props? React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, setstate, react-props

I have a component Home that is called after user get in. There are some data in that screen, and in the header I have a icon button that send the user for a screen where the user can see their profile data and also delete account. So when the icon button is clicked I'm sending data using `props.navigation`, sending the user to another screen/component.

```
profile = () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const user = navigation.getParam('user', 'erro');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('profileScreen', { user: user });
    }
```

Inside the new component, I tried to setState inside the method `componentDidMount` using that data but it didn't work. I checked using `console.log` the data is there. How could I setState in this case?

```
export default class profileScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Profile"
    };

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: {}
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const user = navigation.getParam('user', 'Erro2');
    this.setState({user: user.user});
    console.log(this.state); // Object {"user": Object {},}
    console.log("const user");
    console.log(user.user); //my actual data is printed
}

render() {
    return (
        <Text>{this.state.use.name}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.use.age}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.use.email}</Text>
        ...
        ...
    )
}
```

}

Result from console.log(this.state)

```
Object {
  "user": Object {},
}
```

Result from console.log(user)

```
Object {
  "createdAt": "2019-04-27T21:21:36.000Z",
  "email": "sd@sd",
  "type": "Admin",
  "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T21:21:36.000Z",
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: can add logs that you printed?

Comment: updated with prints from console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to send an object (`user`) as a route parameter with [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) library. It's not possible.

The proper way of doing such scenarios is to send the user's id `userId` as [route parameter](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) and load user details from your API (or state).

```
profile = () => {
        const user = {id: 10 /*, ... rest of properties */}; // or take it from your state / api
        this.props.navigation.navigate('profileScreen', { userId: user.id });
    }



componentDidMount() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const userId = navigation.getParam('userId', 'Erro2');
    // const user = read user details from state / api by providing her id
    this.setState({user: user});
}
```

*ps: if you are using state management like redux/flux/..., consider setting `currentUser` in your global state and read that instead of passing userId as a route param.*

To make sure component updates when the user got new value in the state render method should be like this:

```
render() {
    const {user} = this.state
    return (
      <View>
        {user && <Text>{user.name}</Text>}
        {user && <Text>{user.age}</Text>}
        {user && <Text>{user.email}</Text>}
        ...
        ...
     </View>
    )
}
```

Note 0: `const {user} = this.state` would save you from repeating `this.state`

Note 1: it would much more elegant to wrap all those `<Text>` component inside another `<View>` to prevent repeating the condition phrase `{user && ...}`

Comment: I understand what you said, but I printed the `const user` and I can see the whole data there. So the data have came from the route navigation. Even with that I can't setState? XD too bad I don't know how to use redux yet, planning to learn.

Comment: @Zoro-Zen oh, now I see. you need to render the user when it was populated in your component state. I update my answer.